# Mapping types - automatically remove unspecified properties in type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find the proper and straitforward way to map a complex object into a simpler one.

I wanted to utilize something like this:

```
interface TransferableResponse<T> {
  toServiceResponse(): T;
}

export interface SimpleUserObject {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  expiresIn: number;
  refreshTokenExpiresIn: number;
  roleIds: number[];
}

export class ComplexUserObject implements TransferableResponse<SimpleUserObject> {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  expiresIn: number;
  refreshTokenExpiresIn: number;
  someRedundancy: Guid;
  someWeirdStuff: string;
  complexRoles: [{id: number, name: string}];
  
  constructor(init?: Partial<ComplexUserObject>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  toServiceResponse(): SimpleUserObject {
    return {
      ...this,
      roleIds: this.complexRoles.map(role => role.id)
    };
  }
}
```

So in that case I'm creating `ComplexUserObject` but then, when calling `toServiceResponse()` I would expect to get **only the properties specified in `SimpleUserObject`** . In reality, I'm getting a combination of both (`roleIds`, but also `complexRoles`, `someWeiredStuff` and `someRedundancy`).

Long story short, is there a simple, one-line way of saying `...this` but eliminating stuff that are not included in a type?
Pseudo: `(...this as SimpleUserObject)`

Comment: No, you can't do what you're asking.  What do you think about [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WokpLW) where you define `SimpleUserObject` in terms of your set of keys instead of vice versa?  That is less redundant and behaves as you expect.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will unfortunately always need to manually specify the keys from `ComplexUserObject` you wish to apply to `SimpleUserObject` in some way.

An interface does not exist at runtime, so your code needs to be valid JavaScript when the interfaces are stripped away. There is no JavaScript way of telling the method "take this subset of keys" without explicitly listing those keys somewhere, i.e. manually as keys on the new object, as an array which is iterated, as a reference object which is iterated etc

Your simplest bet is just to list out the new keys

```
toServiceResponse(): SimpleUserObject {
  return {
    accessToken: this.accessToken,
    refreshToken: this.refreshToken,
    expiresIn: this.expiresIn,
    refreshTokenExpiresIn: this.refreshTokenExpiresIn,
    roleIds: this.complexRoles.map(role => role.id)
  };
}
```

You could also use a class instead of an interface (which would allow the resulting concrete instance to become a typed entity even in JavaScript), but will still suffer the necessary manual listing of keys to instantiate the class, just this time in a constructor instead of directly on the returned object

```
export class SimpleUserClass {
  constructor(public args: SimpleUserObject) {}
}
```

```
toServiceResponse(): SimpleUserClass {
  return new SimpleUserClass({
    accessToken: this.accessToken,
    refreshToken: this.refreshToken,
    expiresIn: this.expiresIn,
    refreshTokenExpiresIn: this.refreshTokenExpiresIn,
    roleIds: this.complexRoles.map(role => role.id)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment this is what I'm doing. I wish there was a better way.